# mod_rewrite 2 variables, but only 1 needed in output

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, phpbb

I want to redirect visitors who get to my old phpbb forum URLs to my new URL structure.
`http://mydomain.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=$var1&t=$var2` (f=$var1, t=$var2 are integers)
to
`http://mydomain.com/topic/$var2`

My .htaccess mod_rewrite code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^phpbb/viewtopic\.php\?f=\d+&t=(\d+)$ topic/$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I change the code that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the .htaccess in the root folder of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#place these two lines before any other rules in your .htacess
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)t=([0-9]+)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^phpbb/viewtopic\.php$ /topic/%2? [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you it works! But some minor mistake (doesn't bother me), it adds ?f=4&t=517 in the end of the URL (http://mydomain.com/topic/517?f=4&t=517)

Comment: @ProximityEffect add a `?` to rule as above to remove the query string

Comment: Not quite: [R] defaults to [R=302].  The OP wants a permanent redirect for his purposes.

Comment: So I should change R to R=301 to make it a permanent redirect? (for search engine indexing)

Comment: @TerryE I could not find any reference to `permanent`, but will let OP know. Thanks

Comment: @ProximityEffect If you want the redirect to be `permanent` then use `R=301` i.e. change last rule to `RewriteRule ^phpbb/viewtopic\.php$ /topic/%2? [L,R=301,NC]`. And yes, this is better for SEO

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}        \bt=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule   ^phpbb/viewtopic\.php  topic/%1?    [R=301,NC,L]
```